# Square Live Tile with image collection

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

How do I create 150x150 square live tile with image collection in Windows Phone 8.1? There seem to be no template defined however few apps like People have it.

Answer (score 0):

All the tile templates available are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

Built-in native apps, such as the People hub or Cortana, have access to special live tile templates. As far as I know, there is no way for third-party developers to use them.